# Piping data to Linux program which expects a TTY (terminal)

Tags: linux, terminal, pipe, tty, pty

I have a program in Linux which refuses to run if its stdin/stdout is not a TTY (terminal device). Is there an easy-to-use tool which will create a PTY, start the program with the newly created TTY, and copy all data over stdin/stdout?

The use case is not interactive, but scripting. I'm looking for the most lightweight solution, preferably not creating TCP connections, and not requiring too many other tools and libraries to be installed.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`unbuffer`, part of expect (`sudo apt-get install expect-dev` on Ubuntu Lucid), can fool a program into thinking it's connected to a TTY.

```
$ tty 
/dev/pts/3
$ echo | tty 
not a tty
$ echo | unbuffer tty 
/dev/pts/11
```

Comment: There is a non-production-ready (does not exit properly) reference implementation of unbuffer.c here: http://www.man7.org/tlpi/code/online/dist/pty/unbuffer.c.html I could get the source code (unbuffer.c) from here: http://www.man7.org/tlpi/code/download/tlpi-101113-dist.tar.gz .

Comment: On Mac OS, using homebrew, `unbuffer` can be installed with `brew install expect`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `socat` for this: `echo your stdin strings | socat EXEC:"your_program",pty STDIO >/stdout_file`

For example with `bash`: `echo ls | socat EXEC:'bash',pty STDIO >/tmp/ls_out`

Or as [described here](https://serverfault.com/a/947763/93281), for a program run with `docker`:

```sh
# Run the docker task, here bash, in background
docker run -it --rm --name test ubuntu &
# Send "ls -la" to the bash running inside docker
echo 'ls -la' | socat EXEC:'docker attach test',pty STDIN
# Show the result
docker logs test
```