# "more" command alternative that does support colors?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, colors, ncurses

This is in my top 10 list of tiny annoying things in Linux. I love colored output in terminals: it's nice to see and useful when reading.

The first thing I do on a new system is to set aliases for both `ls` and `grep` to show colored output, and the second is to install `vim` and `htop`.

I use both Gentoo and Ubuntu, and I see that `emerge`, the package manager of Gentoo, has a higher readability than `apt-get/aptitude` just because it uses way much more color output than the latter.

So, whenever I have to pipe an `emerge` command with `more`, all the color is lost and I have to focus my attention on every line to avoid missing anything important.

I can understand that a basic command such as `more` shouldn't depend on `ncurses` (someone could argue that we also have `less`, so one of the two could be even color-friendly), but why there isn't a *famous* alternative to `more` that supports colors, as there is for `vi/vim`, `top/htop` etc.?

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: Oops, [you are right](http://superuser.com/questions/36022/less-and-grep-color). But this works only with `ls` and `grep`. And for other color-enabled commands like `emerge`?

Comment: [... What about it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233808/piping-data-to-linux-program-which-expects-a-tty-terminal)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't get how `unbuffer` works. Can you please provide an example with `ls`, it seems interesting...

Comment: `more` does support color, and it has nothing to do with ncurses.  Try: `printf '\033[31mfoo\033[0;37m\n' | more`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Most commands that can output color have an option to choose between:

- ON: Always output color
- OFF: Never output color
- AUTO: Show color if and only if the output is a terminal

Many commands work automatically in color AUTO mode. That is the case for `emerge`. And that is why you do not have color when you pipe the output: the pioe is not a terminal.

The solution is to tell `emerge` to output the colors unconditionally. And tell `less` not to filter them, of course.

Try:

```
emerge --color y | less -R
```

Comment: @Avio - BTW, you can set `-R` into the `LESS` environment variable. That with `alias grep='grep --color=always'` and `alias ls='ls --color=always'` works beautifully.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I'll do it! Honestly I almost never used `less`, I always thought it was a mere alternative to `more`. Now you'll tell that even `nano` supports colors? :)

Comment: @Avio - Of course! `nano -Y c test.c`. You still have to tweak your `nanorc` file to include the `c.nanorc` or whatever syntaxes you want to enable. But that would be another question...

Comment: Avio - Actually `more` will always show the colors if they are present in the input. The nicest things about `less` IMO are not colors, but that you can navigate the ouput and do searches (with '/').

Comment: Wow, even `nano` has colors! It seems that I blacklisted in my mind too many commands. I suppose I'll have to give them another chance. Yes I think you're right, I'll force myself to use `less` instead of `more` and search text with it. Thank you for all the advices!

Comment: Thanks a lot! `do not have color when you pipe the output: the pipe is not a terminal`. I didn't have this concept before.